# GridView doesn't display data

Tags: c#, gridview, xamarin.android

I'm a beginner in C# and Xamarin. I have this code but I don't know what's wrong with it, that doesn't display data in gridview.

this is the code of my activity:

```
public class MenuFoodActivity : Activity
{
string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "HotelDb.db3");

GridView gv;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
JavaList<String> tvShows = new JavaList<string>();


protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MenuFood);
    gv = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridViewMenu);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, tvShows);            
    Retrieve();

}
private void Retrieve()
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
    var data = db.Table<FoodTable>();
    var data1 = (from values in data
                 select new FoodTable
                 {
                     Shenase = values.Shenase,
                     Types = values.Types,
                     Names = values.Names,
                     Costs = values.Costs

                 }).ToList<FoodTable>();

    tvShows.Add(data1);
    if (tvShows.Size() > 0)
    {
        gv.Adapter = adapter;
    }
    else
    {

        Toast.MakeText(this, "not found.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
}
```

and this one is for axml file:

```
<GridView
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="200dip"
android:id="@+id/gridViewMenu"
android:background="#aaa"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />
```

every thing seems fine and I can enter to the `if` statment but there's nothing in my gridview. Anyone knows what's the problem with this code?
Thanks beforehand.

I've tried to use

```
List<FoodTable> tvShows = new List<FoodTable>();
JavaList<FoodTable> tvShows = new JavaList<FoodTable>();
JavaList<String> tvShows = new JavaList<String>();
```

but they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `List<>` in the **GridView** directly:

```
tvShows.Add(data1);

if (tvShows.Size() > 0)
{
    gv.Adapter = tvShows;
}
```

Comment: This cause an error **cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MainAppHotelXamarin.MenuFoodTable>' to 'Android.Widget.IListAdapter'** @AT-2017

Comment: Try one more thing. Chane the list to this - **JavaList<FoodTable> tvShows = new JavaList<FoodTable>();**.

Comment: Your code looks almost ok. Please visit this link and see if any help provided - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/800908/Displaying-Data-with-an-Adapter-in-Xamarin-Android

Answer (score 0):

> cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Android.Widget.IListAdapter'

You defined the type of `tvShows` as `JavaList<string>`, so when you use `tvShows.Add(data1)` method, the type of `data1` should be `string type`. But your `data1's` type is `FoodTable`, they are incompatible.

As AT-2017 said, use `List<>` will solve this problem, usage like this :

```
//Change the type form string to FoodTable
List<FoodTable> tvShows = new List<FoodTable>();
```

When you add a your list `data1` to list `tvShows`, you could use [List.AddRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474863/addrange-to-a-collection) method :

```
tvShows.AddRange(data1);
```

If you want to display the data of your `FoodTable` in a `GridView`, you could implement a [custom adapter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/grid-view/) :

Create a `GridViewAdapter` :

```
public class GridViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<FoodTable>
{
    private MainActivity mContext;
    private List<FoodTable> tvShows;

    public GridViewAdapter(MainActivity context, List<FoodTable> tvShows)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.tvShows = tvShows;
    }

    public override FoodTable this[int position]
    {
        get { return tvShows[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count => tvShows.Count;

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        FoodTable item = tvShows[position];

        View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        if (view == null) 
            view = mContext.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.item, null);

        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Shenase).Text = item.Types;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Types).Text = item.Types;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Names).Text = item.Names;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Costs).Text = item.Costs;

        return view;
    }
}
```

The **item.axml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="8dp"
   >

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/Shenase"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/Types"
     android:layout_weight="1" />
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/Names"
     android:layout_weight="1" />
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/Costs"
     android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Use it in your code :

```
adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, tvShows);// not use ArrayAdapter
```

Effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Ikm.png).