# Error when converting a foreach into linq

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, refactoring

I have an application that creates courses for a university and adds students to the created courses. I pass the course info from my frontend using a dto for data security. The code in my service, using a foreach works, but the one with the linq does not. The code for my entities, which are students and courses, and my service is below:

```
    public class Student
{
    public string studentName {get; set;}
    public int idCourse {get; set;}
}


public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string courseName {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
    
}

public class CourseDTO
{
    public string courseNameDTO {get; set;}
    public List<string> StudentsFromDTO {get; set;}
}

public class Service(CourseDTO dto)
{
    Course createdCourse = new Course
    {
        courseName = dto.courseNameDTO;
    }
    
    foreach(var studentToAdd in dto.StudentsFromDTO)
    {
        var student = new Student
        {
            idCourse = createdCourse.id;
            studentName = studentToAdd;
        }
        
        createdCourse.Students.Add(student);
    }
    
    // add the created course in the database
}
```

Basically, a course has many students, which are added after the new course is created. In my service I loop through the students names and add each of the individually which is not the most efficient, so I tried to write a linq, but it doesn't work:

```
createdCourse =  createdCourse.AddRange(dto.StudentsFromDTO.Select(s => new Student { idCourse = createdCourse.id;
        studentName = s; }));
```

Any way to refactor the code to be fewer lines or a better linq? Cheers!

Comment: *In my service I loop through the students names and add each of the individually which is not the most efficient* -- why do you believe it is not the most efficient?  Have you profiled?  Is there some performance problem?  Your are mapping a collection of one type to a collection of another type using a linear algorithm, why should there be anything more efficient than that?

Comment: Because it doesn't work...the students name never gets added to my course

Comment: Or by *efficient* did you actually mean **concise**?  Are you looking to do the same thing with less code?

Comment: If your current code doesn't actually work, please [edit] your question to clarify how to reproduce the problem, and ideally share a [mcve].    Your current code doesn't compile by the way, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/IOmrMw.

Comment: I tried to fix the syntax of your code so it compiled.  When I did, the method to create a `Course` from a `CourseDTO` seems to work.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/a9jHCX.  Please [edit] your question to clarify your problem, and see [ask].

Comment: You declared `Students` as a `ICollection<Student>`.  `ICollection<T>` does not have a method `AddRange()`, as `AddRange()` is specific to `List<T>`.  So you have to loop, and add.

Comment: Yes, the method in my service works, but I want to create a course using linq like this: createdCourse =  createdCourse.AddRange(dto.StudentsFromDTO.Select(s => new Student { idCourse = createdCourse.id;
        studentName = s; }));

Comment: Then you need to introduce your own extension method  `AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> destination, IEnumerable<T> source)` such as the one from [AddRange to a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1474863).

Comment: If you are working in C# 9.0 or later, you could simplify your code with a [target-typed `new()` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#target-typed-new), e.g. `createdCourse.Students.Add(new() { idCourse = createdCourse.id, studentName = studentToAdd });`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/s8nCIJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not compile because:

1. You declare `Students` as an `ICollection<Student>`, but [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=net-7.0) does not have a method `AddRange()`.  Only the concrete implementation [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) has [`AddRange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-7.0).

   See *[AddRange to a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1474863/3744182)* for details.

   And of course `Course` does not have `AddRange()` because you never implemented such a method, so neither `createdCourse.AddRange(...)` nor `createdCourse.Students.AddRange(..)` will compile.
2. You are using semicolons in your object initializers:

   ```
   new Student { idCourse = createdCourse.id; studentName = s; }
   ```

   You must use commas.

If you are looking for a one-line method to add all the students to `Course.Students`, you could use [`List<T>.Foreach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach):

```
public static Course FromDTO(CourseDTO dto)
{
    // How is Course.id set?
    Course createdCourse = new () { courseName = dto.courseNameDTO };
    dto.StudentsFromDTO.ForEach(name => createdCourse.Students.Add(new() { idCourse = createdCourse.id, studentName = name }));
    
    return createdCourse;
}
```

Note the use of the [target-typed `new()` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#target-typed-new) (introduced in C# 9.0) to simplify the syntax for object creation when the type can be inferred from the context.

Demo #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7PzBjA).

Alternatively, you could introduce the [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) by [TrueWill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161457/truewill) from *[AddRange to a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1474863/3744182)*:

```
public static class CollectionHelpers
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474863/addrange-to-a-collection
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> destination,
                                   IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            destination.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And do:

```
public static Course FromDTO(CourseDTO dto)
{
    // How is Course.id set?
    Course createdCourse = new () { courseName = dto.courseNameDTO };
    createdCourse.Students.AddRange(dto.StudentsFromDTO.Select(name => new Student { idCourse = createdCourse.id, studentName = name }));
    
    return createdCourse;
}
```

You can't use a target-typed `new()` for `Student` in this case.

Demo #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B0yazt).

While both these approaches are more **concise** than your current code, there is no reason to believe they are more **efficient**.  Your current code and my alternatives all map a collection of one type to a collection of another type in linear time, which would seem to be as efficient as possible.